# How to subscribe a celery task to an existing RabbitMQ exchange?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, grpc, kombu

I'm currently writing a chat messenger using GRPC/RabbitMQ for group chats. I have an API in Django/DRF that handles authentication/message logs/text and email alerts etc.

To do this I would like to create a celery task that subscribes to each group message exchange but I'm unclear if there is there a way to bind a celery task to the message exchanges.

Is it realistic/possible to create celery tasks that subscribe to the chat exchanges I create? If not how would you solve/handle these duties?

Comment: What do you mean by subscribe? What you're asking is possible, but can you describe exactly what would be happening?

Comment: I actually ended up solving this, there's this amazing package called 'yosun' that lets you spawn tasks subscribed to queues

Answer (score 1):

Quick followup, I found an article that detailed using Kombu and Yosun to publish and/or subscribe via Django.

https://medium.com/@benjamin.pereto/microservices-with-django-events-with-publish-subscribe-9cad1c7aee39

Super helpful!